# delete georsslayer with button

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use a button to delete or hide a georsslayer from my map. This code doesn't seem to work

```
var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://econym.org.uk/gmap/lancashire.kml");
    georssLayer.setMap(map);

function deleteLayer() {
    georssLayer.setMap(null);
 }
```

.

```
<div>

     <input type="button" value="delete layer" onclick="deleteLayer();">
</div>
```

I have seen it works with markers: http://jsfiddle.net/TwMVj/3/
Or is this not possible with this API?

Answer (score 0):

It also works with the layer, remove the `var`-keyword when creating the layer to make the layer globally accessible:

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/HNeQa/